# Generalization of Chern-Simons Wilson Line

Tags: string-theory, wilson-loop

The Wilson line in Abelian Chern-Simons theory is

$$\langle\exp\left(i\int dt\dot{x}^{\mu}A_{\mu}\right)\rangle=\int\mathcal{D}A\exp\left(i\int dt\dot{x}^{\mu}A_{\mu}+\frac{i}{4\pi}\int A\wedge F\right).$$

The above path-integral is Gaussian and can be solved. I want to generalize this on a worldsheet, but I don't know much about string theory.

Let $B_{\mu\nu}$ be a $2$-form field, and $H_{\mu\nu\rho}$ is a $3$-form field such that $H=dB$. $B$ and $H$ are defined in the target space.

Does it make sense to write the following action,

$$\int dzd\bar{z} B_{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu}+\int B\wedge H,$$

where $B=B(X)$?

Comment: FWIW, the 5-form $B\wedge H$ can only be integrated over a 5-dim manifold.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes I want the target space to be five dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Two-form fields like your $B_{\mu\nu}$ are know as Kalb-Ramond fields. There is a Wikipwedia article on them, and a large literature.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please say something about the action?

Comment: I don't use these things myself, so I have little  useful to say. But knowing their name should give you access to the literature where your question may be addressed.